# How Android OS recognizes network calls on main thread and throws NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-source, networkonmainthread

I'm trying to find the part of AOSP's source code which is responsible for guarding for making network calls on main thread and throwing `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as a result but so far I failed.

**So how Android recognizes network calls on main thread?** Does it check if some network component (maybe it happens in HW layer?) of the OS was touched?

Thanks for *Michael Dodd* answer I found where the exception is thrown (you can find it by [this search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onNetwork%20user%3Aaosp-mirror&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=)). Now the question is who and when calls the `android.os.StrictMode.onNetwork()` method.

Comment: your question is?

Comment: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/121eb58ab44fb3290a1b0452019efe718422576e/core/java/android/os/StrictMode.java

Comment: @ZUNJAE Don't you see the question at the top "How Android recognizes network calls on main thread and throws NetworkOnMainThreadException"?

Comment: I can't understand WHY DOWNVOTING?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Michael Dodd answer I found how it works, e.g. [for Android 8](https://github.com/search?l=&p=2&q=onNetwork%28%29%20language%3AJava%20repo%3Axdtianyu%2Fandroid-8.0.0_r4&type=Code) there is:

```
/**
 * Resolves a hostname to its IP addresses using a cache.
 *
 * @param host the hostname to resolve.
 * @param netId the network to perform resolution upon.
 * @return the IP addresses of the host.
 */
private static InetAddress[] lookupHostByName(String host, int netId)
        throws UnknownHostException {
  BlockGuard.getThreadPolicy().onNetwork();
  // ...
}
```

and (thanks to Michael Dodd) in [android.os.StrictMode](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onNetwork%20user%3Aaosp-mirror&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) you can find:

```
// Part of BlockGuard.Policy interface:
public void onNetwork() {
    if ((mPolicyMask & DETECT_NETWORK) == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if ((mPolicyMask & PENALTY_DEATH_ON_NETWORK) != 0) {
        throw new NetworkOnMainThreadException();
    }
    if (tooManyViolationsThisLoop()) {
        return;
    }
    BlockGuard.BlockGuardPolicyException e = new StrictModeNetworkViolation(mPolicyMask);
    e.fillInStackTrace();
    startHandlingViolationException(e);
}
```

The `mPolicyMask` sets the `PENALTY_DEATH_ON_NETWORK` via `android.os.StrictMode.enableDeathOnNetwork()` from [android.app.ActivityThread.java](https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-8.0.0_r4/blob/01cb57ccba12dba1e3c9f695fad0c673a5a44186/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java):

```
/**
* For apps targetting Honeycomb or later, we don't allow network usage
* on the main event loop / UI thread. This is what ultimately throws
* {@link NetworkOnMainThreadException}.
*/
if (data.appInfo.targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    StrictMode.enableDeathOnNetwork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to [Anton A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735097/anton-a) for the initial pointer, the section of code responsible for throwing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is `StrictMode.java`, located within `frameworks/base/core/java/android/os`.

This is the function in question. As far as I'm aware this has remained the same since at least Android 4.3.

```
// Part of BlockGuard.Policy interface:
public void onNetwork() {
    if ((mPolicyMask & DETECT_NETWORK) == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if ((mPolicyMask & PENALTY_DEATH_ON_NETWORK) != 0) {
        throw new NetworkOnMainThreadException();
    }
    if (tooManyViolationsThisLoop()) {
        return;
    }
    BlockGuard.BlockGuardPolicyException e = new StrictModeNetworkViolation(mPolicyMask);
    e.fillInStackTrace();
    startHandlingViolationException(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is for sure sth to start with but this is just the result of "detecting network on main thread"; I'm asking about how Android actually detects that network call was made on main htread ... but thanks anyway

Comment: `Alt + F7` or `Find usages`, and follow the rabbit hole up. There are probably way too many instances of this being used in the AOSP code base to list in a single answer here. That's assuming you've run the `idegen` script to create the relevant files to import the AOSP  code base into IntelliJ or Android Studio.